# Add cell within tableview row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

[curent table row display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJDgP.png)

I have a tableview as shown in the image, when I presses any of the button (sun, mon etc), it adds a new row in a similar format. I want to add a row (line bar, with text opening hours and x button ,as shown in image) when the user presses, opening hours, in the same row.These can be multiple. Thanks in advance.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    NSMutableArray * dataSource;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"array", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [dataSource count];
}

- (WorkHoursCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"WorkHoursCell";
    WorkHoursCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorkHoursCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell.btnTapped addTarget:self action:@selector(sundayTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.monTapped addTarget:self action:@selector(mondayTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//    DayName *day = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return  cell;
}

-(void)sundayTapped:(id)sender {
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:0]];

    [dataSource insertObject:@"new row" atIndex:indexPath.row+1];

    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)tempArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: please add your code in question?

Comment: Updated, check image for cell UI details

Comment: I would also tag this with the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

**(1)** Prepare a Array which will be a Datasource for your Array.

**(2)** Whenever user presses any of the button (mon, tue etc), prepare a dictionary which contains information like day, open, close.

**(3)** You will have to update your datasource, that is once user adds a day. Means add a dictionary in the Array. For example, if user added TUE, THU, MON, SUN. Then your Array will contain four dictionary.

**(4)** Reload the Table. Based on that, your data will be presented in the cell.

Add a comment in case of any query !!!